# Kafka proxy as intermediate

Tags: apache-kafka

We are currently looking into investing in a company-wide Kafka-as-service (Paas) with one of the major kafka providers (like IBM, Confluent, Heroku, etc).

Common for all of these is that they provide username+password authentication for data producers and consumers.

One of our key CDC replication software does not support this authentication method, and can only work with no-authentication or 2-way certificate TLS authentication.

What can we introduce as intermediate proxy technology (on windows) that can be provide no-authentication on internal network and connect using username+password towards public kafka broker?

It may be open-source or commercial solution.

CDC Replication --- (no authentication) ---> Proxy --- (username + password) ---> Kafka broker

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple you could just have a second non-secure Kafka cluster. Stream your CDC to that, and then use a tool such as MirrorMaker or Confluent Replicator to stream the CDC topic(s) to your secured cluster.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*

Comment: that is an option, but i would prefer a light weight proxy solution which can be installed on the same server as the CDC - if such a proxy exists.

Comment: I think this kafka-proxy does exactly what you are looking for:
https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy